# returning data from checkboxes in mvc 2 view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using checkboxes in the view of my MVC2 project to allow users to select multiple objects. Here is the code in my view(skipping unrelated lines:

```
<h2>Install New Equipment</h2>


//Html.BeginForm("CreateRequest1", "Home", FormMethod.Post);  
<div>Employee's First Name:  <%= Model.Employee.EmpFName%></div>

<div>Employee's Last Name:       <%= Model.Employee.EmpLName%></div>

<div>Employee's Phone Number:   <%= Model.Employee.Phone%> </div>
<br />

<div>Please select the equipment you would like to request:</div><br />
<div> <% foreach (var info in ViewData.Model.EquipDescription)
          { %>
        <% = Html.CheckBox("Description", info.ID) %><%=info.Description%>  <br />
    <%} %>
     </div><br />

      <div>Please Select the Location for the Equipment to be Installed  </div><br />
<div>Building  <%= Html.DropDownList("NewBuildings", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["buildings"], "ID", "Buildings")) %>
   Floor <%= Html.DropDownList("NewFloors", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["floors"], "ID", "FloorNumber")) %>
    Office<%= Html.DropDownList("NewOffices", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["offices"], "ID", "OfficeNumber")) %>

</div>
<br />

<div>Comments: <%=Html.TextArea("Comments") %></div><br />
```

<%Html.EndForm(); %>

(I removed the `<%%>` around the begin form line so my whole post would show)
Everything display perfectly in the view. I recieve all the other data from the user. I just don't know how to recieve the data from the selected checkboxes

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateRequest1(int NewBuildings, int NewFloors, int NewOffices, string comments, int[] Description)
```

What should I add here to get the selected values?

Comment: I changed view controller method to start with [HttpPost] public ActionResult CreateRequest1(int NewBuildings, int NewFloors, int NewOffices, string comments, ICollection<int> Description) and ICollection<int> Description is still empty

Comment: I also tried ICollection<EquipDescription> Description in the collection method and it is also empty. Are my Checkboxes created correctly?

Comment: Someone Please help me I've tried EVERYTHING I can think of even int[] Description, I have been using google and trying EVERY example I can find. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I DON'T KNOW WHAT or where to even look anymore

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a parameter to your method like:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateRequest1(int NewBuildings, int NewFloors, int NewOffices,  string comments, ICollection Description)

I assume your value is an int, but you can change it if required.

You can read more here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: I changed my [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateRequest1(int NewBuildings, int NewFloors, int NewOffices,  string comments, ICollection<int> Description)
        {

Comment: I changed view controller method to start with [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateRequest1(int NewBuildings, int NewFloors, int NewOffices,  string comments,  ICollection<int> Description)
        and  ICollection<int> Description is still empty
        and

Comment: I also tried ICollection<EquipDescription> Description end it is also empty

Comment: What is the type of each EquipDescription as that'll be the array, or just try:
EquipDescription Description in your method.

I'll keep an eye out and see how you go with that.

Comment: ok so explain this to me maybe it will help. I've created my checkboxes in a loop. I THINK the way I set it up the checkboxes are named "Description" the value is the ID of the object its being create from and it is displaying the Description attribute. What happens when one or more checkboxes are selected? Since they are created in a loop and the number and values will vary how is that handled? How are/should the selected values be returned to the controller method?

Comment: Should I declare an ICollection in the view to contian the selected values? If so how is that done?

Comment: You won't need to declare ICollection in the view.

In terms of how the values come to the controller. When you check a box that value will be posted, otherwise it won't come through on the controller.

The selected values should then come through on the controller where you use a foreach loop to iterate through each of those values and handle them how you need to.

Comment: wow ICollection<Boolean> finally returned something THANK YOU for your help and patience